# How to stop booting getting stuck at Eco erase error

Tags: windows

I am booting my pc but it keeps getting stuck on an 'eco erase' error. Very occasionally it will boot through to windows. I have no idea what it is and how to stop it:
[image]

Image transcript:

```
Eco Erase Version: 27august1-dev
Fingerprint by Eco Erase (C) 02-10-2020 18:35
    Disk Wipe ID: ...
    Disk Serial#: ...
Sanitation by Eco Erase (C)
    Method: Custom (Char: 0x0)
    Passes: 1
    Result: PASSED
SMART Test (short) by Eco Erase (C)
    Result: SMART 0
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you (or someone else) start to erase the HDD? If so, it would be hard to boot with a wiped disk.

Comment: It looks like some kind of hard disk wiper that is set to blank out parts of your harddrive on boot (possible secure wipe of deleted files?). Did you install extra security tools on your pc?